# Access XAMPP from Internet

Tags: apache, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on my PC. I am trying to make my XAMPP server accessible through the internet.

I can access this through my internal IP, but not my external IP. I have port forwarded the port used correctly and I checked it to be open, however when using my external IP, it just shows a blank screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the httpd-xampp.conf file to comment out the "Require local" line

Comment: It still shows up as blank, I've edited all of the require all's to require all granted. The require locals were already edited out before hand.